# how to send email from an android application

Tags: android

I have tried this till now

```
register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Username = username.getText().toString();   
                Email = email.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("clicked register Button");
                System.out.println(" User name is :" + Username );
                System.out.println(" Email Id is :" + Email);


                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , Email);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , Email);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "You are registered for Aero india");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Get the print out of this email while coming to the venue");
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: It 's not working? I get a new window when i click register it has to "to" text area where when i type an email id , the send button changes to "send MMS"

Answer (score 9):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
* Class which shows how to send email
*
* @author FaYna Soft Labs
*/
public class Main extends Activity {
    private Button clickBtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        clickBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
        clickBtn.setText("Send email");
        clickBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                String[] recipients = new String[]{"my@email.com", "",};
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is email's message");
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use email.setType("message/rfc822"); to prompt user email app only. without it, all available app with send action will be prompt for selection.