# Send Email in Service (without prompting user)

Tags: android, email, service, android-intent

is it possible that I send email in background using service.. like in service I use Intent with ACTION_SENDTO with Uri data mailto:recipient_email and it get sent in the background without any user intervention .. or through default email app without prompting the user ...

Comment: you want to send email programmatically?

Comment: yes but using the user's configured email not any other email

Comment: check these solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345032/how-to-send-a-simple-email-programatically-exists-a-simple-way-to-do-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456688/how-to-send-email-from-an-android-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is using the Gmail account to send the email.

Generally speaking:

1. download mail.jar and activation.jar for android https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/
2. Connect to GMail to get the OAuth token
3. Send the email

here's the code

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.URLName;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;
import com.sun.mail.util.BASE64EncoderStream;

public class GMailSender {
    private Session session;
    private String token;


    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public GMailSender(Activity ctx) {
        super();
        initToken(ctx);
    }

    public void initToken(Activity ctx) {

        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(ctx);

        Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            Log.d("getToken", "account="+account);  
        }

        Account me = accounts[0]; //You need to get a google account on the device, it changes if you have more than one


        am.getAuthToken(me, "oauth2:https://mail.google.com/", null, ctx, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>(){
            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result){
                try{
                    Bundle bundle = result.getResult();
                    token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                    Log.d("initToken callback", "token="+token);    

                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d("test", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, null);

        Log.d("getToken", "token="+token);
    }



    public SMTPTransport connectToSmtp(String host, int port, String userEmail,
            String oauthToken, boolean debug) throws Exception {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "false");

        session = Session.getInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
        SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
        // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
        final String emptyPassword = null;

        /* enable if you use this code on an Activity (just for test) or use the AsyncTask
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
         */

        transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);

        byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1",
                userEmail, oauthToken).getBytes();
        response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);

        transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response), 235);

        return transport;
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String user,
            String oauthToken, String recipients) {
        try {

            SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com", 587,
                    user, oauthToken, true);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                    body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(user));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(recipients));
            smtpTransport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("test", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

this code was originally posted here [Javamail api in android using XOauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503303/javamail-api-in-android-using-xoauth).

Please note to get the OAuth token you need an Activity and you have to ask the user which account to use. The token should be retrieved during the OnCreate phase and saved in the preferences. See also [How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address?lq=1)

Alternatively you can use mail.jar but you have to ask the user for their username and password.

Comment: You can get the oauth token from a service too, using public AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> getAuthToken (Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options, boolean notifyAuthFailure, AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> callback, Handler handler)  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: can you tell me, where do I get this whole functionality?  I have created GmailSender class and integrate google login but i am not able to send mail in background