# Sending e-mail on Android automatically

Tags: android, email, gmail

In order to send an e-mail without user intervention from my devices (Nexus7 & Samsung galaxy S5) I followed the procedures described in
[Send Email in Service (without prompting user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517079/send-email-in-service-without-prompting-user/29089263#29089263)

and 
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android

Both sent the e-mail correctly, but I always end up with a popup message
"Gmail has stopped" on my device, which is not very thrustworthy for the users of my App and by which makes both solutions unusable.

Is there another solution, or how can I get rid of this error?

Logcat shows the following errors:

```
03-17 11:44:32.324: I/Gmail(2797): Sending provider changed intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://gmail-ls/unread/^i (has extras) }
03-17 11:44:32.341: I/Gmail(2797): Sending provider changed intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://gmail-ls/unread/^iim (has extras) }
03-17 11:44:32.365: I/Gmail(2797): notifyAccountChanged
03-17 11:44:32.368: I/Gmail(2797): getAccountsCursor
03-17 11:44:32.369: W/Gmail(2797): Sync complete for account: account:-654877552
03-17 11:44:32.379: W/GAV2(2797): Thread[SyncAdapterThread-1,5,main]: dispatch call queued.  Need to call GAServiceManager.getInstance().initialize().
3-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797): FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797): Process: com.google.android.gm, PID: 2797
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:630)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.aV.b(SourceFile:6237)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.bh.HC(SourceFile:4213)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.bh.<init>(SourceFile:4186)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.bo.a(SourceFile:3898)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.Operations.b(SourceFile:628)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.aV.a(SourceFile:5936)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailSync.a(SourceFile:899)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.a(SourceFile:2432)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.a(SourceFile:2129)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.bp.a(SourceFile:127)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.common.b.onPerformSync(SourceFile:33)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.bp.onPerformSync(SourceFile:82)
03-17 11:44:32.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2797):     at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259)
03-17 11:44:32.417: I/NotifUtils(2797): Validating Notification, mapSize: 1 getAttention: true ignoreUnobtrusive: false
```

Comment: I used an SMTP service (mailgun, though there are others), rather than having the device itself send.  No sign that there is an email sent.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get a stack trace of the error that is causing Gmail to stop? If you are on Android Studio, it will be under `logcat`.

You may need to remove the filter for the log by selecting the dropdown on the far right of the logging area and selecting **No Filters**.

This will help you troubleshoot the error causing this crash.

**Related**: I'd suggest moving the logic for sending an email to a server, where you can better monitor delivery, spam compliance (in the US), and usage rates. If you don't need to send the email as the user, this may be a better solution.